# BadMethodCallException in /bootstrap/cache/compiled.php when calling chunk on Eloquent Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am receiving `[BadMethodCallException] Method isNotEmpty does not exist` whenever I am using chunk method on a Eloquent Model. 
I am receiving this error on all my servers (testing, staging and production) but not on my local machine even though all 4 machines have same versions of php, laravel.

**Stacktrace**

> [2019-02-25 11:51:04] staging.ERROR: BadMethodCallException: Method isNotEmpty does not exist. in /api/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php:6366
>   Stack trace:
>   0 /api/vendor/baopham/dynamodb/src/DynamoDbQueryBuilder.php(430): Illuminate\Support\Collection->__call('isNotEmpty', Array)
>   1 /api/app/Console/Commands/IndexInvoicesToElastic.php(142): BaoPham\DynamoDb\DynamoDbQueryBuilder->chunk(10000, Object(Closure))
>   2 [internal function]: App\Console\Commands\IndexInvoicesToElastic->handle()
>   3 /api/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(1257): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
>   4 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(169): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
>   5 /api/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(256): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>   6 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(155): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>   7 /api/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(794): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>   8 /api/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(186): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(App\Console\Commands\IndexInvoicesToElastic), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>   9 /api/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(117): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>   10 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(107): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>   11 /api/artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>   12 {main}

**Version info**
Laravel: 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the method isNotEmpty [on Laravel 5.2 collections documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-isempty).
isNotEmpty [was introduced on 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-isnotempty)

Comment: But this method is present 
 in this file `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php` and the laravel version on my local machine and server is `Laravel Framework version 5.2.45`.  
If this method was introduced in Laravel 5.3, then this method wouldn't have worked on local machine

Comment: I can't find no reference to isNotEmpty on Laravel 5.2, https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php Are you sure you have installed the same version on your local machine? You can check it by doing: 'composer info | grep laravel/framework ' on your project

Answer (score 1):

**Laravel 5.2** doesn't support [isNotEmpty](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-isnotempty) and it was introduced in **[Laravel 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-isnotempty)**. But why don't you use something simple like this:

```
// If collection exist
if($yourCollection) { 
  // your code
} else {
 //do something else
}
```